# Fraternisation amongst directors of our charity

Tags: relationships

Ok, so I've been volunteering at my local hackspace for several years now.

Soon after joining I noticed a pattern of the organisation consistently struggling with things like project planning, deadlines, communication, and volunteer management, so I tried to help by sharing some of my experience.  After almost two years of trying in vain I decided to run to be a director.

Cut to a few months later and I'm one of 3 new directors in our growing organisation.  The two previous directors were also re-elected so that makes a board of 5.

It's been almost a year now since the election and very little has changed.  In my mind, this is due to systematic blocking of change requests by the previous two directors.

This in itself is not an issue, as it is within their rights to make a case to resist change.  It's just *how* they do it that troubles me.

When I first met them they told me they were a couple, but they were keeping it a secret from the organisation to avoid complications.  At the time I was uncomfortable with this, but let it slide.  Now that I work with them I see that it affects their judgement significantly.

Both of them have very chaotic personal lives, which make it very difficult for them to engage with the rest of the board.  They both have a habit of not following protocol, failing to deliver on time, failing to offer progress updates, you name it.

Depending on what our most recent scandal is, one of the two in the couple will agree that the other is a problem.  Sometimes the man believes the woman needs intervention.  Sometimes is the other way around.

I've reached the point where I don't think either of them are fit to do their jobs anymore.  Unfortunately, because of the history of the organisation, they still hold almost all the power and influence when it comes to making decisions.

I am convinced that they are using their relationship to keep each other in power, despite what is best for the organisation.  Even though I know they frequently disagree with each other, they always end up voting in tandem.

I don't want to reveal their relationship to the rest of the board, but I believe it is my responsibility to flag that it may impair their judgement.

**Question:**
Should a relationship like this, in a board of directors, be disclosed to the rest of the board?

We are a UK charity/company and as far as I can tell, legally, there is no requirement for this.  Ethically, on the other hand, I am not sure.

Comment: Do any of the organizations rules or bylaws prohibit this type of relationship among directors, or require disclosure?

Comment: The short is: No, not explicitly.  The long answer is:  We haven't finalised our legal structure yet, so we don't actually have article of incorporation that state how we operate.  Well, we do, but they are default off-the-shelf articles that we didn't write.

Comment: Then assuming that the standard articles do not forbid it(most I have ever seen do not) then you have no "Obligation" to report it.  So it is merely a decision about do you want to try to raise the issue with the board in hopes of changing those rules.  We can not make that decision for you so this question is off topic here.  You could change the question to ask how to go about changing the rules to forbid it if you want. That would be on topic

Answer (score 2):

Even if everyone knew about their relationship, would that solve the problem? If the two are constantly functioning as a faction within the board, always siding with each other and defending each other, I'd think that on a five person board that would be pretty obvious. When something like that happens, whether it's because the two have a romantic relationship, if they are just friends, or if they just generally agree with each other over what is best for the organization (rightly or wrongly), doesn't make much difference. If you're concerned about the ethics of revealing personal information, don't. If the other members of the board don't notice that these two always vote the same, point it out without mentioning their romantic relationship. Just say, "Hey, notice that Bob and Sally always vote together."

In any case, what difference does it make? Suppose you told everyone about their relationship. Then what? In the absence of a rule against it, it's not grounds to have one or both kicked off the board. "I think it's inappropriate" is not much of an argument. They could simply reply, "Why? We don't see anything wrong with it."

Of course we, reading your post, have no way to know if the policies you prefer are really better. No insult intended, but without knowing any of the details, there's no way to know if you're right and they're wrong or vice versa. But assuming your policies really are better, you have to convince two other members of the board. If you can convince these two, then you have a majority. If not, then you have to convince the other two.

Further thought: Forget the ethics for the moment. As a purely tactical matter: If you exposed personal information about these two that they want to keep secret, that would surely set them against you. Even if they became convinced that your ideas were better, they might continue to vote against you out of resentment. On the flip side, would revealing their relationship make the other two board members more likely to vote with you? Without knowing more about the personalities involved it's hard to say, but my guess would be that the answer is "no". I've been a member of such boards. If someone told me that two other board members were secretly having a relationship, I might or might not think that inappropriate. But I can't imagine it would lead me to say, "I'm therefore going to vote for anything that they vote against." It's unlikely it would change my vote at all.

So frankly, I think by revealing the relationship you would guarantee losing 2 votes, with no particular reason to believe that you would gain any.

Comment: Our policies don't say much of anything.  We have identified this as a problem before, but every time we try to establish a code of conduct or some core director responsibilities, or an accountability structure, the two problem directors perpetually delay the issue and no changes happen.  The three new directors have each taken turns to complain about this, but we haven't acted in concert yet because we're not sure what that would accomplish.  They have all the control and all the responsibilities and are very sensitive.  Any strong confrontation will result in them shutting us out.

Comment: And even if we took the harsh approach and kicked them out, we have strong reason to believe they wouldn't transfer their knowledge, contacts, projects, etc and that would put the organisation at risk.  We feel like we're held hostage.

Comment: @HackspaceDirector, If you want to establish a code of conduct, write a draft of that code of conduct yourself. Don't expect it to get it done from scratch during a board meeting. Also, don't bring a copy of it to the board meeting just like that. Meet with each Director individually to show them the code of conduct you came up with and ask for their input. Show it to the couple as well, but again, show it and discuss it with them individually. I'm sure you'll find you'll have no trouble passing it unanimously if you do it that way.

Comment: As to the accountability structure, separation of duties https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_duties , and proper financial controls, that' s going to be trickier to implement. People hate to implement proper financial controls, especially if they've been allowed to run an organization without them for so long. So I would try adding those procedures slowly over time, after you've already passed the code of conduct, but again, I wouldn't count on the group to create those procedures from scratch, and you'll need to draft those procedures mostly yourself before talking to others.

Comment: If you were to introduce a code of conduct that explicitly prohibits romantic relationships between board members, and these two know that you know that they are having such a relationship, they would surely perceive this as being all about them. If I was on a 5-member board and someone proposed a new rule that outlawed something that I was doing, and that I knew this person knew I was doing, at the very least I'd be suspicious. And even if you got the new bylaws passed, you'd still have to reveal this personal information for it to make a difference. And then what? Are you going to ...

Comment: ... kick them off the board? Force them to break up? If you force them to break up, who's going to watch them 24x7 to make sure they're not secretly meeting? And even if you could prevent them from dating, will that stop them from voting together? Unless you're prepared to kick them off the board, I don't see what you'd gain.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. This being in the UK, this is actually a tricky situation.

As an officer of this organization, I believe it's your fiduciary duty to make sure that the rest of the board, your counsel, and your accountant be informed of this relationship. **That being said, don't jump the gun just yet!** You should read my entire answer and then you should consult with your organization's legal counsel in the UK to ask how/if you should proceed.

> About conflicts of interest
>
> You have a legal duty to act in your charity’s best interests when
>   making decisions as a trustee. If there’s a decision to be made where
>   a trustee has a personal or other interest, this is a conflict of
>   interest and you won’t be able to comply with your duty unless you
>   follow certain steps.
>
> https://www.gov.uk/guidance/manage-a-conflict-of-interest-in-your-charity

Why should this be important to you a member of the board? The emphasis in **bold** is mine.

> If trustees don’t follow the principles of decision making:
>
> - **they could be responsible for financial loss** or reputational damage to the charity
> - their decision could be invalid, or might have to be reversed
> - they could **open the charity to the risk of legal action**, and **themselves to the risk of personal liability**
> - the commission might have to get involved and use its powers to protect the charity’s property and put things right
>
> https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/its-your-decision-charity-trustees-and-decision-making/its-your-decision-charity-trustees-and-decision-making

For instance, if the relationship ever breaks up, your organization needs to insulate itself from any potential quid pro quo sexual harassment claims.

And for that to occur, if it's not already the case, there should be clear rules about the couple not being allowed to have power over each other, not being allowed to formally review each other's work performance, not being allowed to decide each other's schedule, not being allowed to sign/authorize/audit/vote on each other expenditures/receipts, etc.

Now here comes the tricky part. Again, the emphasis in **bold** is mine.

> **Q: Can an employer insist upon its employees disclosing workplace
>   relationships?**
>
> A: While an employer can potentially ask its employees to disclose
>   such relationships, again a blanket request that this is done by all
>   employees may be challenged on the basis that it represents an
>   **infringement of their right to respect for their private and family
>   life under the Human Rights Act.** There is also the question of the
>   penalty that would be imposed upon any employee who chose not to
>   disclose this information. If employers feel that it is important that
>   workplace relationships are disclosed, **it is usually only in
>   situations that present risks to the business (e.g. the manager/team
>   member type of relationship)** which are most likely to give rise to the
>   sorts of practical and legal risks referred to above. It would
>   therefore be preferable, and **put the employer in a better position in
>   terms of any Human Rights Act challenge, if the employer identified
>   particular risk situations to which a disclosure obligation attaches.**
>
> https://www.frettens.co.uk/site/library/frettensnews/employment_law_Managing_workplace_relationships

Or if the relationship goes too well, your organization also needs to make sure that both parties are never tempted to just drain the entire organization's bank account and run away to Maui together in case both have signatory powers on a two-signatures-required account.

This is not to say that those two should be penalized for their relationship. They shouldn't be. But if they have any kind of power over each other, or if they could use their position of directors to potentially collude and defraud the organization, some degree of disclosure should be done and some rules should be put into place to safeguard your organization from either of these possibilities. Not putting these safeguards in place would be considered a dereliction of duty as a board member and could open you up to all kinds of problems.

And this issue is ultimately not even with those two in particular. These two won't be the first, nor the last, that have a relationship with each other, especially if your hackerspace grows bigger, gets more directors, and employs more people. So ultimately, this is something that you need to consider when drafting your by-laws, and this is something that your legal counsel will have to review to make sure it's legal in your jurisdiction.

By the way, I think you should read [The Partnership Charter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738208981) by David Gage

That book is about business partnerships, but many of its concepts would still apply equally well to brand new non-profits. It was written by a professional mediator who usually has to resolve disagreements after new companies have already gone up in flames because of partnership disputes. So he decided to write this book as a way for partners to try to mitigate these kinds of problems in advance, or perhaps even to have potential partners cut their losses and move on quickly before they get themselves in too deep.

Comment: + 1 for the suggestion of the book. Reference material about ethics and not related to any sort of potential legal issues, just the mediation issues. Even beyond the legal QPQ issues, having a partner in a concurrent position can lead to vindictive behavior (I'll just vote against you, because pettypettyblahblah). Good answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the very helpful answer.  I appreciate that my question is fairly open ended and difficult to answer, but you have still managed to help.  Cheers.